# How can i fix Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, ios, flutter, gradle, dart

could someone help me with this error please ?
(I added packages dependencies and nothing changed. for example, for audioplayers package, I add path_provider and uuid).

am using latest version of flutter, android studio, gradle

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try downgrading gradle version.

Flutter always faces some major issue with latest version of gradle